# How to pass parameters through a button action between View Controllers?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

New to objective-C and working on a media player project. I currently have 2 view controllers:

- `MenuViewController`
- `PlayerViewController`

In `MenuViewController` I have a button action that creates an instance of `PlayerViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)showPlayer:(id)sender
{
    PlayerViewController * vc = [[PlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayerViewController" bundle:nil];


    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

}
```

When the button is pressed and `ViewPlayerController` has loaded, it automatically starts a video playing. What I would like to do is create a number of buttons on `MenuViewController` and pass parameters through each one (for example: "video1", "video2", "video3", etc.) then be able to use an if statement in my `PlayerViewController` so that it checks the parameter and plays a video based on which button is pressed. Is it possible to attach a parameter onto vc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I would like to do is create a number of buttons on MenuViewController and pass parameters through each one

Just set some property of `PlayerViewController` after you create it and before you present it:

```
- (IBAction)showPlayer:(id)sender
{
    PlayerViewController * vc = [[PlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayerViewController" bundle:nil];

    vc.someProperty = @"video1";

    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

You can do anything you want to configure `vc` as necessary before you present it, including calling various methods, giving it the data it needs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Your PlayerViewController have a property called videoIdentifier, and set this to under action method of button of MenuViewController like

```
- (IBAction)showPlayer:(id)sender
{
PlayerViewController * vc = [[PlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayerViewController" bundle:nil];
vc.videoIdentifier = sender.title

[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

}

And in your PlayerViewController compare videoIdentifier property under if else of switch statement to play the video you want.

Comment: Have button's title set as per your requirement like "video1", "video2", "video3", etc.